# How to regularly check if a client has disconnected from WebSocket http Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, websocket

(I didn't really understood other solutions.)

I'm streaming a webcam video from a browser client (index.html) to a WebSocket server (app.js/node.js).
The server is receiving these frames encoded as base64 and generates images `out.png` inside a `static/img` folder.

I would like to delete this `out.png` image after the client stopped streaming.

```
const wsServer = new WebSocket.Server({ server: httpServer });

// array of connected websocket clients
let connectedClients = [];

wsServer.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
    console.log('Connected');
    // add new connected client
    connectedClients.push(ws);
    // listen for messages from the streamer, the clients will not send anything so we don't need to filter
    ws.on('message', data => {
        // send the base64 encoded frame to each connected ws
        connectedClients.forEach((ws, i) => {
            if (ws.readyState === ws.OPEN) { // check if it is still connected
            // create static image of the base64 encoded frame
            fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './static/img/out.png'), data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, ""), 'base64', function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
            } else { // if it's not connected remove from the array of connected ws
                connectedClients.splice(i, 1);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I tried this approach which looks like it would make sense. But `.on("close")` is not actively checking if the streamer is still connected. How can I do that? So, the server should regularly check if the streamer stopped streaming and clean up the mess which he/she left behind :)

```
// If the client is not streaming or stopped streaming
wsServer.on('close', (ws, req) => {
    console.log('Disconnected');
    // delete last image if streamer does not send new messages
    fs.unlink(path.resolve(__dirname, './static/img/out.png'), function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all: `".on("close") is not actively checking if the streamer is still connected."` It does not have to check, hes not connected. He closed the connection, that is the whole point of web socket, too not need to check constantly for activities.

Comment: thats the point why im asking this question :)
im asking if there is a way how to do cleanup tasks after the streamer is disconnected from the server